# Punctuation spacing after long exponents

Tags: math-mode, spacing, footnotes

When typesetting equations with long exponents or high-numbered footnotes right before punctuation marks, the result is a rather awkward large space between the last letter and the punctuation mark:

```
\setcounter{footnote}{138}
{\Huge
$X^{\mathrm{red}}$, blah\footnote{}.
}
```

resulting in

[image: large whitespace before punctuation marks]

Now, I'm not sure that this would actually look better, but is there an (elegant, i.e. no manually inserted negative whitespace ....) way to have the `.` and `,` appear *under* the exponent?

EDIT: To avoid confusion: I'm interested to find out whether it's *possible* to have the `,` in `$X^{\mathrm{red}}$,` treated like the `0` in `$X_{0}^{\mathrm{red}}$`. Whether this behaviour is *advisable* is, of course, an entirely different question!

Comment: +1 An interesting question, but I don't know if anyone would ever recommend doing this. You would be asking the reader to parse the exponent (or footnote) at the same time as the punctuation, which would be confusing. The way it stands in your MWE, the reader parses the two things separately, which is much more digestible. Still, an interesting question nonetheless :)

Comment: I pretty much concur with @cmhughes.  There are times, though, when I'm bothered by the punctuation as the end of a mathematical expression.  I don't have issues with the commas internal to the expression.  But I and my students can be distracted by an *apparently* dangling comma or period.  To get around this *annoyance,* I usual find another way to rewrite what I wrote in order to avoid a sentence ending with the mathematical expression capped by punctuation.  Probably not the answer you're looking for---hence I've only put it in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

The space is only apparent:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\tryrule}{\leavevmode\smash{\kern-.2pt\vrule height\ht\strutbox\kern-.2pt}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{footnote}{137}
$X^\mathrm{red}$\tryrule, blah\footnote{xyz}\tryrule, blah\tryrule,

$X^\mathrm{red}$, blah\footnote{xyz}, blah,

$X{\hskip\scriptspace\scriptstyle\mathrm{red}}$, blah{\hskip\scriptspace\scriptsize139}, blah,
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first line the rule is just to show precisely the division between the characters (it takes up no space, as shown by the second line). In the third line the objects are shifted to the baseline.

You *may* want to insert a negative thin space:

```
$X^\mathrm{red}$\negthinspace, blah\footnote{xyz}\negthinspace, blah,
```

[image]

---

The remark cgnieder made in a comment is very worth noting! The `fnpct` package allows for very fine control about the footnote mark placement, with its

```
\setfnpct
```

command.

Comment: I think there might have been some misunderstanding ... I wanted the punctuation mark _underneath_ the exponent, i.e. directly after `X` or `h`, under `r` and `1`, respectively. In other words, I'm looking for similar behaviour as `$X^{235}_{0}$` only with my punctuation mark where the `0` is. As @cmhughes pointed out above, this might be even more confusing than a big space but I thought trying it out coldn't hurt (too much :)).

Comment: @Jonathan The comma underneath an exponent in a math formula would be definitely wrong. Somebody uses footnote marks *after* punctuation, rather than above it. Say `\rlap{,}\footnote{text}` to get the footnote mark above the comma.

Comment: @Jonathan while the comma really shouldn't be placed underneath an exponent the [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) package gives you means to control the interaction of footnote marks and punctuation